# How to make a text field visible if it is initially hidden during run time?

Tags: java, swing

The problem is that at run time textField is hidden. But when jButton1 is selected it still remains hidden. Here is the Code:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jTextField1.setVisible(t);}

static boolean t=false;

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String qty=jTextField2.getText();
        int q=Integer.parseInt(qty);
        if(q!=0)
        jTextField1.setVisible(true);
    }    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that text from `jTextField2` is parsed so something else than 0? Also you should `revalidate` the container holding `jTextFIeld1`

Comment: yes, if have entered all possible in jtextfield2 but still the textfield1 remains hidden

Comment: if possible can you write the codes

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does not use the NetBeans GUI editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, so if I were to guess, when you were testing this, you were entering non integers into the text field, and throwing a NumberFormatException at

```
int q = Integer.parseInt(qty);
```

Try this and see if it works for you.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String qty=jTextField2.getText();

    try {
        int q=Integer.parseInt(qty);
        if(q!=0) {
            jTextField1.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // you know it can't be 0 if it got here
        jTextField1.setVisible(true);
    }
```

If you want to ensure the user enters an integer into the textfield, you could put an InputVerifier on it.

You could also keep it as a string instead of converting it to an integer and do this:

```
if (!qty.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
}
```

Comment: *"If you want to ensure the user enters an integer .. you could.."* ..use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So double click on the jbutton1 or however you normally do it in netbeans (sorry, haven't used netbeans in about 6 months) to set the code when the button is click and just set the relevant textfield's visibility to true... basically what the answer below this says... :)

Comment: Still having the same problem.......

Comment: Can anyone just explain how to hide a text field initially when the run Window appears and then make it visible it if a button or check box is selected ?